# show full name on hover limitTo Content Using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a products array.it consist of name,price,qty. i am Using limitTo When name length reaches to 20. 
when hover on product how to show full name please hlep me?

```
<p class="hover">{{ item.name| limitTo: 20 }}{{item.name.length > 20 ? '...' : ''}}<p/>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `title` property

```
<p class="hover" title="{{item.name}}">
```

or if you what to use angular for it and not the tooltip

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
$scope.myText = "some very very very very very long text";
})
.directive('hoverText', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            hoverText: '=',
            maxChars: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
          element.text(scope.hoverText.substr(0, scope.maxChars) + '...')
            element.on('mouseenter', function() {
                element.text(scope.hoverText);
            });
            element.on('mouseleave', function() {
                element.text(scope.hoverText.substr(0, scope.maxChars) + '...');
            });
        }
    };
})
```

```css
p
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
  <p hover-text="myText" max-chars="20">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is shows tool tip. but don't want tool tip.expand on the same place.

Comment: ok i added an alternative directive, i recommend the directive method, because it is reusable in your code + if you have a loop for your products using a flag for mouseenter and leave will trigger all of them! unless you make it a property in the product item itself

Comment: if you can add that library to your code i would also highly recommend it... i also use it constantly

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like below.

**Markup**

```
<p class="hover" ng-mouseenter="limit=item.name.length" ng-mouseleave="limit=20">
    {{ item.name| limitTo: limit }}<span ng-bind="limit > 20 ? '...' : ''"></span>
<p/>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.limit = 20;
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/s6lqPtszrBZjmpaTpvwp?p=preview)

---

Though I would suggest you to look at CSS option where you can achieve the same using `text-overflow: elipsis` and making `overflow: hidden`. You can refer [**this link**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/) to implement the same

Comment: @WalksAway I see, that's why you updated your answer.. I don't want to repeat same thing in my answer, but your way seems awesome to me. :)

Comment: @WalksAway that was my next step I'm gonna do, but I head out for something in between, and you did the same. Therefore I won't be able to do it now :)

Comment: @WalksAway though I would love to use `text-overflow: elipsis` CSS property, I can't now. I'll upvote yours if you want :p I did it +1

Comment: yeah it is better but i had issues with it, like when you want to have multiple lines + ellipsis, it only gives you the first line